# Validating input size and value into an "EditTextCell" GWT Datagrid

Tags: validation, gwt, input, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with two editable columns (EdiTextCell). I was wondering if i could control the input value in the first one : Value can only be "R" or "". In the second column (EditTextCell also) the value (String) length must be < 2.

I didn't find an issue to control the value every time it changes to prevent input and clear cell content if not "R" or "" in the first case. in the second case i should stop input if 2 chars.

Any help please?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see an example by searching Google for CellTableFieldUpdaterExampleComplex. Basically, in the `FieldUpdater` associated with the column you just need to do the following:

```
cell.clearViewData(KEY_PROVIDER.getKey(object)); 
cellTable.redraw();
```

Comment: How to get `cell` reference in `FileUpdater`?

Comment: @masterdany88 I'm sorry, but I don't remember how to do that! It's been too long since I used GWT.

Comment: @masterdany88 Save a reference to the cell when you create it, and use this reference in the FieldUpdater (I'm assuming you meant "Field" and not "File").Take a look at the example (I've fixed the link in my original answer), and look for the name cell/name column updater.